# Mac Numbers: How to replace the original column values with original column values times two?

Tags: macos, apple-numbers

**Mac Numbers:** How to replace the original column values with original column values times two?

For example, for column B2, I have

```
B2
--
2
4
6
8
10
```

How to change to

```
B2
--
4
8
12
16
20
```

Comment: I only have "Paste" and "Paste and Match Style" in my mac Numbers

Comment: Create formula (e.g. in column c) with 2 * the value in column B. Then copy column C and go to B2 and do “Edit” » “Paste Formula Results” (shift+command+V).

Comment: It works! Thank you Rob!